# Difficulty in understanding a proof about bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

**Statement:**

Let **G[X, Y ]** be a bipartite graph without isolated vertices
such that
$$
d(x) ≥ d(y)\:\: \forall xy\in E, where \: x\in X \: and\: y\in Y. 
$$
Then 
$$
|X|\leq|Y|
$$
with equality if and only if d(x) = d(y) $$\forall xy\in E.$$
**Proof:**
The first assertion follows if we can find a matrix with **|X|** rows and
**|Y |** columns in which each row sum is one and each column sum is at most
one.

Such a matrix can be obtained from the bipartite adjacency matrix **B** of **G[X, Y ]** by dividing the row corresponding to vertex x by d(x), for each
x ∈ **X**. (This is possible since d(x) = 0.)

Because the sum of the entries of **B** in the row corresponding to x is d(x), all row sums of the resulting matrix  **B'** are equal to one.

On the other hand, the sum of the entries in the column of **B'** corresponding to vertex y is 
$$
\Sigma 1/d(x)
$$
the sum being taken over all edges
xy incident to y.

This sum is at most one because 1/d(x) ≤ 1/d(y) for
each edge xy, by hypothesis, and because there are d(y) edges incident to y.

The above argument may be expressed more concisely as follows.
$$
|X|=\sum_{x\in X}\:\sum_{y\in Y \: xy\in E} \frac {1}{d(x)} 
     =\sum_{x\in X \:y\in Y}\:\sum_{xy\in E}\frac{1}{d(x)} 
     \leq \sum_{x\in X \:y\in Y} \: \sum_{xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(y)}
     =\sum_{y\in Y}\:\sum_{x \in X \: xy \in E} \frac{1}{d(y)}=|Y|
$$

Furthermore, if $$|X|=|Y|$$ the middle inequality must be an equality, implying that 
$$ 
d(x)=d(y) \:\: \forall xy\in E.
$$

I don't understand

- how the first assertion follows from finding "a matrix" in which each row sum is one and each column sum is at most one.
- what is the matrix **B'**
- the equation with lot of sigmas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on every edge $xy$ of the graph you write the number $\frac{1}{d(y)}-\frac{1}{d(x)}$, then the sum of all these numbers equals $|Y|-|X|$. On the other hand the sum is nonnegative (by your assumption) and if $d(x)>d(y)$ (strictly) for at least one edge, then the sum is strictly positive. That's all.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation? I am not able to make much sense of the proof.

Comment: It is the same as your solution but in an easier language. Which part would you like me to expand? It might help if you write it out on a small example. If I start to make it very detailed then it will become precisely what you wrote, and that you had a problem with in the first place.

Comment: I tried a small example but it seems like magic. I am not able to understand the arguments made in proof. Graph theory seems to be full of proofs and  understanding how the arguments are laid out would help a lot.

Comment: The way you wrote this @MichalAdamaszek was how the proof should have been written. Crisp and elegant. Very nice! Meanwhile the proof written in the OP seems tortured no wonder why the OP struggled to follow.

Comment: @Mike there seems to be only torture ahead :-P